# How to add a component to an existing HTML using Webfirmframework?

Tags: java, html, wffweb

I am trying to generate a dynamic HTML using Java and the webfirmframework.

Is there a way to build individual components like Table and Div without enclosing them in Html() ?
I have over 10+ pieces of business logic and each generates an individual table of data. All these 10+ tables must be displayed inside a HTML.

Creating a single method for generating all these 10+ tables is making the code unreadable.

Requirement is to be able to build individual components and then concatenate them together to generate the final HTML page.

This is what I tried and it throws errors.

**`The constructor Table(MyServiceClass, CustomAttribute, CustomAttribute) is undefined`**

```
private void generateTable(final MyCSS hcCss) {
        new Table(this,             
            new CustomAttribute("cellspacing", "0"),
            new CustomAttribute("cellpadding", "3")) {{
            new TBody(this) {{
                new Tr(this) {{
                    new Td(this,
                        new Style("padding: 3px")) {{
                        new NoTag(this, "XXXX");
                    }};
                }};
            }};
        }};
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of a tag class is its parent class, in your case `Table` tag has no valid parent so you have to pass `null` instead of `this` argument if you want to generate table without outer html tag.

Modify your code as follows

```
private void generateTable(final MyCSS hcCss) {

        Table table = new Table(null,             
            new CustomAttribute("cellspacing", "0"),
            new CustomAttribute("cellpadding", "3")) {{
            new TBody(this) {{
                new Tr(this) {{
                    new Td(this,
                        new Style("padding: 3px")) {{
                        new NoTag(this, "XXXX");
                    }};
                }};
            }};
        }};

        System.out.println(table.toHtmlString());
}
```

But for your actual requirement, here is the sample code

```
public class TableComponentMethods {

    public static void embedTable1In(Body body) {

        new Table(body,             
            new CustomAttribute("cellspacing", "0"),
            new CustomAttribute("cellpadding", "3")) {{
            new TBody(this) {{
                new Tr(this) {{
                    new Td(this,
                        new Style("padding: 3px")) {{
                        new NoTag(this, "XXXX");
                    }};
                }};
            }};
        }};

    }

    public static void embedTable2In(Body body) {

        new Table(body,             
            new CustomAttribute("cellspacing", "0"),
            new CustomAttribute("cellpadding", "3")) {{
            new TBody(this) {{
                new Tr(this) {{
                    new Td(this,
                        new Style("padding: 3px")) {{
                        new NoTag(this, "Table 2");
                    }};
                }};
            }};
        }};

    }

}

public class WffWebTest extends Html {

    private Body body;

    public WffWebTest() {
        super(null);
        setPrependDocType(true);
        develop();
    }

    private void develop() {
        body = new Body(this);
    }

    public Body getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WffWebTest finalHtml = new WffWebTest();

        // this will add table as a child in Body tag
        TableComponentMethods.embedTable1In(finalHtml.getBody());
        TableComponentMethods.embedTable2In(finalHtml.getBody());

        System.out.println(finalHtml.toHtmlString());

    }
}
```

This will print

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 3px;">XXXX</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 3px;">Table 2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

**Updated**

Since [wffweb 2 version](https://webfirmframework.github.io/developers-guide/get-started.html), you can use `appendChild` method to [add child to a tag](https://webfirmframework.github.io/developers-guide/tags-and-attributes.html).

Comment: @user811433 Welcome!